# Storage was accessed before it was initialized [HydratedBloc]

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc

I am facing issues when working with hydrated bloc in flutter. I am trying to persist some data but I get an error each time.

```
Storage was accessed before it was initialized.
Please ensure that storage has been initialized.

For example:

final storage = await HydratedStorage.build();
HydratedBlocOverrides.runZoned(
  () => runApp(MyApp()),
  storage: storage,
);
```

This is strange because I am currently initialising it correctly.

```
Future<void> main() async {
  //Because hydrated bloc communicates with the native code, we must first ensure everything is natively initialised.
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  final storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
      storageDirectory: await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory(),
  );
  HydratedBlocOverrides.runZoned(
        () => runApp(MultiRepositoryProvider(
      providers: [
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => AdviceRepository()),
        RepositoryProvider(
          create: (context) => FavouritesRepository(),
        )
      ],
      child: const MyApp(),
    )),
    storage: storage,
  );
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: MultiBlocProvider(
        providers: [
          BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => AdviceBloc(
                RepositoryProvider.of<AdviceRepository>(context),
              )..add(LoadAdviceEvent())),
          BlocProvider(
              create: (context) => FavouritesBloc(
                RepositoryProvider.of<FavouritesRepository>(context),
              )),
        ],
        child: const Home(),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Is this an issue with the way I am using MultiBlocProvider or MultiRepositoryProvider widgets?

I am saving data into the bloc like this:

```
  context.read<FavouritesBloc>().add(AddFavourites(
                          AdviceModel(slip: state.advice.slip!)));
```

Comment: What version of hydrated bloc were you using at the time of asking the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
  HydratedBloc.storage = await HydratedStorage.build(
      storageDirectory: kIsWeb
          ? HydratedStorage.webStorageDirectory
          : await getTemporaryDirectory(),
  );
```

use with path_provider package for web support.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting HydratedBloc initialization immediately after this line.

```
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
```

Worked for me (using version hydrated_bloc: ^9.1.3) .